# JavaScript alert callback not working inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a image preview containing of about 5-6 images which will appear one after another when user hovers over it (not like a carousel with prev and next buttons). Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wP3QQ/4/) consisting of what I gathered so far.. i don't know if this approach is right or not.. but I am stuck as the alert callback is not working. Could someone please tell me what is wrong?

```
$(function() 
  {
      var imageCount = $('#product_grid_list').find('figure')[0].getElementsByTagName('img');

      for (var i = 0, n = imageCount.length; i < n; i++) {
          imageCount[i].on('click', function(e) 
              {
                  alert('Everything is going fine!');
              }          
          );
      }
  }
);
```

Comment: Why not use jquery selectors to select imgs?

Comment: okay i see what i was doing wrong.. thanks to all you beautiful people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of click event callback can't be triggered is that you're trying to register a event handler on a "DOM" (in this case: **imageCount[i]**) element in jQuery way. Try to register the event handler like this if you want to use pure javascript solution:

```
imageCount[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
    alert('Everything is going fine!');
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wP3QQ/12/).

Note: I didn't consider the cross browser issue in this case.

BTW, try to cache the length of imageCount node list, it will improve the performance.

Comment: so we are not supposed to use jquery event method when using standalone JavaScript for loop ??

Comment: In fact, jQuery supports multiple elements event registration, it means that you don't need to use a loop to register event handler per HTMLElement when you decide to use jQuery. Furthermore, I suggest to adopt [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) strategy to this case.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to call `on()`, a jQuery method, on an `HTMLElement` (a DOM element). You can't do that, jQuery methods can only be called on jQuery collections. It's easy to get a jQuery collection for the elements you desire:

- Use `.find()` to match the images
- There's no need for a `for()` loop, jQuery's `.on()` will handle looping for you.
- You may also want to prevent the default behaviour of your anchors

```
$(function () {
    var imageCount = $('#product_grid_list').find('figure img');
    imageCount.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        alert('Everything is going fine!');
    })
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wP3QQ/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You are using js AND jQuery at same time. It's wrong. If you use jQuery, than `click` event will be like this:

```
$(document).('click', '#product_grid_list figure img', function(){
     alert('Everything is going fine!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a mix of jQuery and standalone javascript. You might as well go all the way to jQuery, with something like:

```
$('#product_grid_list figure:first img').click(function(e) {
      alert('Everything is going fine, hopefully!');
   });
```

You did not send the corresponding HTML, so we cannot test whether the above is correct.

Answer (score 1):

it's just a simple click event in jQuery, no need to use js: http://jsfiddle.net/wP3QQ/11/

```
$('#product_grid_list').find('figure img').click(function(e){
    alert('Everything is going fine!');
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the hover effect, so click event should not be used over here. It should be mouseover.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wP3QQ/10/)

Code Snippet:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','#product_grid_list  figure  img',function(e){
      alert("now it is working");
});
```